# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field
```

In the line:

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle bundleRequest = msg.getData();
        String packageName = bundleRequest.getString("packageName"); // <-- here
    // etc...
```

Of an Android Remote Service.

this is the full stacktrace:

```
10-12 11:02:36.235 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field
10-12 11:02:36.235 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Field.setIField(Native Method)
10-12 11:02:36.240 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Field.setInt(Field.java:778)
10-12 11:02:36.240 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1095)
10-12 11:02:36.245 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
10-12 11:02:36.245 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
10-12 11:02:36.250 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
10-12 11:02:36.250 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
10-12 11:02:36.255 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
10-12 11:02:36.255 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
10-12 11:02:36.255 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
10-12 11:02:36.260 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
10-12 11:02:36.260 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
10-12 11:02:36.260 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
10-12 11:02:36.265 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
10-12 11:02:36.265 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
10-12 11:02:36.265 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
10-12 11:02:36.270 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
10-12 11:02:36.270 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
10-12 11:02:36.270 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1488)
10-12 11:02:36.270 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:759)
10-12 11:02:36.270 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
10-12 11:02:36.275 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
10-12 11:02:36.275 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
10-12 11:02:36.275 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
10-12 11:02:36.275 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
10-12 11:02:36.280 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
10-12 11:02:36.280 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
10-12 11:02:36.280 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
10-12 11:02:36.280 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
10-12 11:02:36.280 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
10-12 11:02:36.285 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2220)
10-12 11:02:36.285 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2071)
10-12 11:02:36.285 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
10-12 11:02:36.285 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
10-12 11:02:36.285 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
10-12 11:02:36.290 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at package.service.remote.ActionsRemoteService.handleMessage(ActionsRemoteService.java:411)
10-12 11:02:36.290 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at package.service.remote.ServerRemoteService$IncomingHandler.handleMessage(ServerRemoteService.java:56)
10-12 11:02:36.290 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-12 11:02:36.290 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-12 11:02:36.290 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
10-12 11:02:36.295 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 11:02:36.295 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-12 11:02:36.300 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-12 11:02:36.300 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-12 11:02:36.300 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
10-12 11:02:36.300 18565-18565/package:remote W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how can i fix this error?

Edit: Adding the method where i populate the value:

```
final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // etc
            try {
                // RSE_REGISTER_CLIENT is 0
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null, RSE_REGISTER_CLIENT); 
                msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
                Bundle bndlResponse = new Bundle();
                bndlResponse.putString("packageName", context.getPackageName());
                msg.setData(bndlResponse);
                mService.send(msg);
                // etc
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are populating this `Bundle`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i added the code in the question.

Comment: That's rather strange. The stack trace shows Android attempting to de-serialize a `Serializable` that is in a `Bundle`. Are you sure that there are no other scenarios in which you are sending a `Message` to this `Handler`?

Comment: there are more scenarios, yes, but others are successful Messages, the error ocurrs in that line, but sometimes have errors and sometimes does not have errors, like everyone, i want a stable app, not sometimes app. This error is so strange, yes... im testing in the api 19 of Android.

Comment: You set the "Message.what" value to "RSE_REGISTER_CLIENT". I wonder whether the 'Incoming Handler' should check this "what" before processing the bundle (to be sure you're reacting to your own message, as a handler will receive all kinds of messages on the UI-Thread). - I'm not posting this as an answer because it's a "try this " approach. Without more code I can't reproduce the problem - sorry

Comment: it works in 25 cases more, the only case where fails is in the provided code. I think is an Android bug, sometimes runs successful sometimes brings the exception.

Comment: The exception is about Reflections where im not touching reflections.